# SQL subquery into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, subquery

I am basically from a SQL Server domain, now learning MongoDB. I want to convert into MongoDB native query for the following scenario.

I have two tables `[Marks], [Student Details]`:

**[Marks]** table has the following structure:

```
StudentID Varchar(10),
Marks Int
```

**[Student Details]** table has following structure:

```
StudentID Varchar(10),
StudentName Varchar(50),
Age Int,
Address Varchar(500).
```

Now I want to retrieve top 5 student who got high marks using following SQL query.

```
Select * From [StudentDetails] 
where StudentID in (Select Top 5 StudentID from [Marks] order by Marks Desc)
```

I want to convert this query into MongoDB, how can I achieve this?

Comment: How is you data represented in MongoDB?

Comment: If you consider NoSQL schema design strategies, you should make a single table `Student Details` with `Marks` as a field in that as there is one to one relationship between them according to your design

Comment: You can take any data in MongoDB, i want to know how to achieve SubQueries in MongoDB.

Comment: Yes i agree dev, on NoSQL schema design strategies.

Comment: @selvakumar then querying is also easier for you. `db.collection.find().sort({"Marks":1}).limit(5)`

Comment: you can simply achieve this using its java or any other drivers

Comment: This is my real scenario, i have posted the related question.

1. Group by and getting count based on CustID field.
2. Sorting Count value with Desc, and Select only 100000 records.
3. Added 100000 distinct CustID into BsonArray.
4. Then Added $in operator with BsonArray, Group by and getting sum of Amount fields.

Comment: 5. Those Group by are using Aggregate pipeline. This query takes more than 2 hours.
6. My Collection has More than 20 Million records, DB size is 80 GB, I have created Index for Grouping Fields. But i want to improve performance.

Note: My Group by output are stored into another collection using $out parameter, if there is any way to filter only new collection data in $in operator without BsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a single collection, say student, with a document which has the following schema, for instance:

```
{
    "studentId": "7402B",
    "name":  "foo",
    "age": 19,
    "address": "1 abc street",
    "marks": 78
}
```

To retrieve top 5 students who got high marks would be simply:

```
db.student.find().sort({ "marks": -1 }).limit(5)
```

The [**`sort()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) method specifies the order in which the query returns matching documents, where the value of -1 to specifies a descending sort. The [**`limit()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) cursor method then specifies the maximum number of documents the cursor will return, in the above only the top 5 would be returned.

In the event that you have two separate collections then you would need two queries, one that gets the student Id's from the marks collections using the cursor's [**`map()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) method and then the other query that returns the documents with the student ids from the students collection:

```
var studentIds = db.marks.find()
                         .sort({"marks": -1})
                         .limit(5)
                         .map(fuction (doc){ return doc.studentId; });
db.students.find({ "studentId": { "$in": studentIds }});
```

Comment: Thanks, But this is not i actually want, I have two collection data, i want to filter master collection based on another collection values.

Comment: 5. . Those Group by are using Aggregate pipeline. This query takes more than 2 hours. 6. My Collection has More than 20 Million records, DB size is 80 GB, I have created Index for Grouping Fields. But i want to improve performance. Note: My Group by output are stored into another collection using $out parameter, if there is any way to filter only new collection data in $in operator without BsonArray.

Comment: ar studentIds = db.marks.find()
                         .sort({"marks": -1})
                         .limit(5)
                         .map(fuction (doc){ return doc.studentId; });
db.students.find({ "studentId": { "$in": studentIds }});   This query is working fine when we have a small set of Id values to find, But consider more than 20 million records, and limit is 10 lakhs, Then the query takes more than an hour.  Is this the right way to add all the values in $in statement? or else there is any special way to do it. consid all the Id from the first query are stored in one Collection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can not do it in one query but I can help you with some other strategy.

```
var topmarks = db.Marks.find({ "marks" : -1 }).limit(5).toArray();
db.student.find({ "studentId" : { "$in" : topmarks } });
```

Comment: Consider DB has 20 million document, limit(10 lakhs) documents then MemoryOutofExceptions are thrown in C#.NET.